# Multiply each column of a numpy array with each value of another array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Suppose I have the following two numpy arrays:

```
In [251]: m=np.array([[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]])

In [252]: m
Out[252]: 
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]])

In [253]: c= np.array([200,400])

In [254]: c
Out[254]: array([200, 400])
```

I would like to get the following array in one step, but for the life of me I cannot figure it out:

```
In [252]: k
Out[252]: 
array([[200, 800, 400, 1600],
       [400, 1000, 800, 2000],
       [600, 1200, 1200,2400]])
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The transformation you want is called the Kronecker product. Numpy has this function as `numpy.kron`:

```
In [1]: m = np.array([[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]])

In [2]: c = np.array([200,400])

In [3]: np.kron(c, m)
Out[3]: 
array([[ 200,  800,  400, 1600],
       [ 400, 1000,  800, 2000],
       [ 600, 1200, 1200, 2400]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.concatenate` along with list comprehension:

```
np.concatenate([m * x for x in c], axis=1)
```

This gives you

```
array([[ 200,  800,  400, 1600],
       [ 400, 1000,  800, 2000],
       [ 600, 1200, 1200, 2400]])
```